# Fastest Database Software

Tags: php, search, c++, facebook

I would like to make my own search engine. I would like to know the best way to go about this. I just have some questions ...

1. Should I use Facebook's HipHop PHP to C++ compiler for speed?
2. What would be the fastest kind of database software for searching through billions of web pages ( eventually )

Thanks for your help!
Francis

Comment: You want to search billions of **web-pages** by using **database software**? Database is used to store data, not to search.

Comment: Rather than using database you can use **BigData**.

Comment: What's BigData?

Comment: I think it will be better you study that by yourself. Just google it, you will get what you need.

Comment: This is, in essence, a software development question, which makes it off topic here. Also, it's much too broad. Entire books have been written about this. There's no single answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old computer problem and has been well solved already hundreds of times.

To give you a little context I've been using data bases for about 36 years, since 1977, and there were good data bases for many years before I was using them.

Now, I can see that you are interested in computers and software which I think is cool.  I suggest you buy some books on the subject and begin to learn more of what is out there before starting off building what has already been built.

Good luck on your education, there is still much to be done in this world with computers that has not yet been done.  For example I would like to have an efficient code editor that uses more than my fingers for input, as they get tired.  I think it would be great to think thoughts and have them interpreted.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm just curious, is Amazon Dynamo DB suitable for storing billions of web pages? It says it's highly scalable.

Comment: You might want to DuckDuckGo 'ACID' as it relates to data bases.  Also look up 'BASE'.  And thanks to you right now I'm also updating my education and learning about newer graph data bases.  As it turns out there are lots of different ways of organizing data, and lots of different types of data and various questions that one could ask of data.  So the devil is in the details, as always.  The question is what do you want to store and scale?  And then how can that best be done?